# Change the order of title and featured image in Wordpress twenty twelve theme excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

When I have a page that displays post summaries, the order of items are as follows:

1. Featured Image without link
2. Title
3. Summary

What I want is

1. Title
2. Featured Image with link
3. Summary

When I look into the code of the theme (content.php), I come across a function called the_excerpt(). I can't find this function in the theme and therefore can't update it.

```
<?php if ( is_search() || is_home() || is_tag() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
```

So my question is

1. Is there a way to change the order of the title and featured image in this theme?
2. How can I add a link to the post to the featured image, so that when the reader clicks on the picture, they land on the post.

Comment: there should be a file named archive.php look at it...

Comment: I added the code that I have, it is in content.php. I couldn't find anything relevant in archive.php.

Comment: the excerpt is merely creating, well, an excerpt of the post itself, it has nothing to do with the featured image or the title. Look around the excerpt function call and you should find them (look for; `the_title()` and `the_post_thumbnail()`)

Comment: oh and for your second question; use [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I got the link and the order correct. Now, I'm working on the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move around the "pieces" and add some CSS to make it look good.

In the `archive.php` - replace the content of the `header` tag (and the tag itself) with the following code:

```
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h1>
        <?php endif; // is_single() ?>

        <?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ! is_attachment() && !is_single() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
            <div class="comments-link">
                <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .comments-link -->
        <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

Please note, that you'll have to add some styles to .entry-title, as there's no spacing below it and it doesn't look okay.

Comment: I had to add && !is_single() to the if before the_post_thumbnail() and add the permalink to a href around it. For some reason, this code is in content.php in twenty-twelve. Not I have to adjust the css to have the spacing correct. Unfortunately, I can't upvote your answer, because my points are less than 15.